# ipdb arrows keys produce escape sequences

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipdb

I"m on `Python 3.6.6, Jupyter console 5.2.0, Ipython 6.4.0, Ubuntu 18.04`. When in ipdb, arrows keys produce escape sequences instead of moving the cursor. I have `readline` installed and `libncurses5-dev` installed. What's the issue?

More data: this is only true in jupyter console, everything works fine when running `ipython` directly.

Comment: do you have a `~/.inputrc` ?

Comment: no, there is no `.inputrc`